# How to make XMLHTTP request execute python cgi script?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, cgi

in my code I have a button which, upon being clicked, calls a javascript function I made, named loadXMLdoc(). This function is supposed to create an xmlhttprequest and send that request to a .cgi script I wrote (in python). However, it is not causing the .cgi script to execute. Below is my javascript function (written in  of my index.html).

```
<script>
    function loadXMLdoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "cgi-bin/run.cgi"
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                $.getJSON('cgi-bin/output.json', function(result) {
                    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                        prompt(field[1]["firstName"])
                    }) 
                })              
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send()
    }
</script>
```

And here is my run.cgi script in a directory titled "cgi-bin":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import system

system("rm output.json")
write_file = open("output.json", 'w')
write_file.write('{"employees":[\n')
write_file.write("\t" + '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},' + "\n")
write_file.write("\t" + '{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}' + "\n")
write_file.write("]}")
write_file.close()
```

But, when loadXMLdoc() is called by clicking the button, run.cgi isn't being executed. That is, it is not rewriting output.json. So, at the moment, clicking the button brings up a prompt saying "Peter". However, if I change the Peter to Emily in the cgi script above, the output.json will not be rewritten if I call loadXMLdoc() through clicking the button. Isn't sending the xmlhttprequest to the .cgi supposed to cause the cgi to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the cgi script has the permission to execute (chmod +x) and also check if the script has permission to write in the directory.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but still no luck. Also, if I just do "python run.cgi" via command line, it rewrites the output.json fine.

Comment: What is the user/group? For example, in one of my test server, it's www-data and www-data.

Comment: Can you make a change in your code? Instead of creating the output.json file in the current directory, create it in /tmp/
write_file = open("/tmp/output.json", 'w')
Also comment out the line : system("rm output.json")
Now check if your cgi script can create this file.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your webserver config, it's not going to be possible to determine why the call is not being routed to your cgi-bin script.  I recommend you check your webserver logs to see what's recorded after each hit. That might give you a clue why your code is not being called.

Also, just taking a stab in the dark, but your javascript url "may" not be correct. Could you try?

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/cgi-bin/run.cgi"
```

NOTE: I added a forward slash **before** cgi-bin.